# Can you restrict meta reload?

Tags: html, reload, meta

so I'm trying to use meta reload to update my website (using the code below) and I was wondering if it was possible to make it reload once after opening the page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" >
```

Why, because looking at a website that refreshes every 3 seconds is really annoying to look at. If you can help, thank you.

Comment: You'd likely need to use JavaScript for this, because you'll need to store outside of the context of the page some indicator that the page has already reloaded and then read that indicator any time the page loads.  Local storage would be a reasonable place to store that information.  Though there's probably a better overall approach to whatever it is you're implementing.  Why do you need the page to reload at all?

Comment: The page won't update until it's refreshed, so every time I add something or change something in the code, I have to refresh the page.

Comment: Again, there's *probably a better overall approach* to whatever it is you're trying to do.  But if you're insisting that you *must* refresh the page because you *want* to refresh the page, then certainly go ahead and refresh the page.  But to store some indicator of whether or not the page has already been refreshed, take a look at something like local storage using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do to make it update once when the page was loaded was change index.html to index.php
Thank you with all the help you guys gave me, but this is all I ended up needing to do. I still very much appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

@David's comment (original post)

To store values without files and within the webpage. I suggest you encrypt the data because it is visible in the developers console 'local storage'

```
function holdArray(array){
    localStorage.setItem("holdArray", array);
    return true;
}
function releaseArray(){
    if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty('holdArray')){
        return localStorage.getItem("holdArray");
    }
}
```

Set data

```
holdArray(JSON.stringify(yourvariable));
```

Get data

```
let storage = releaseArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, once I get my website back up and running I'll try that